# Using the position of <div> to subtract inside my click event?

Tags: jquery, css

For the #box2 left and top values, I need to subtract the actual width and height of #box2 itself, which comes from the .css file. I tried to do .css({left:event.pageX - .css(width:200px);.... with no luck. Below is my existing snippet without the subtraction part.

```
$('.lightbox2').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#box2').css({
        left: event.pageX,
        top: event.pageY
    });
    $('.backdrop, #box2').animate({
        'opacity': '.50'
    }, 300, 'linear');
    $('#box2').animate({
        'opacity': '1.00'
    }, 300, 'linear');
    $('.backdrop, #box2').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: @Joe - where did your answers go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var box = $('#box2')
var w = box.width();
var h = box.height();
box.css({
    left: event.pageX - w,
    top: event.pageY - h
});
```

Comment: bfavaretto's solution worked - only now it triggers the lightbox event when you load the page... http://masterfade.com/maptest/ ... ? The link that is beeing used for testing is the "door" T symbol halfway down the page on the right hand side...

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding you wanted to do something like this,

```
var box = $('#box2');
box.css({
    left: box.position().left - box.width(),
    top: box.position().top - box.height()
});
```